# what is process and update and how it works in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Can you differentiate process and update.Since am new to JSF am little confused where to use.unnecessary use causing issue in my Application.

Answer (score 25):

`process` in primefaces equals to `execute` in JSF

> process : Determines id’s of components to be processed(sent/submitted
>   to server).

`update` in primefaces equals to `render` in JSF

> update : Determines id’s of components to be updated (refreshed with
>   updated values from server).

If you want to learn about those two tags (and more) you should read this blog post :

[Learning JSF2: Ajax in JSF – using f:ajax tag](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)

After that you should know that primefaces `process` and `update` can also use a more powerful selectors, read more here

[jQuery Selector API meets JSF](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867)

and

[PrimeFaces Selectors - @(selector)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks for the simplest answer...